How to prevent duplicate $PATH entries?
I am trying to add $HOME/.local/bin:$PATH to my $PATH. I added it in .zshrc like so: export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
Each time I source the configuration file, the entry gets prepended again:
echo $PATH

/Users/kamil/.local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/utilities
❯ sz
zsh configuration loaded...

░▒▓ ~  echo $PATH                                ✔ ▓▒░

/Users/kamil/.local/bin:/Users/kamil/.local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/utilities

░▒▓ ~  sz                                        ✔ ▓▒░
zsh configuration loaded...

░▒▓ ~  echo $PATH                                ✔ ▓▒░

/Users/kamil/.local/bin:/Users/kamil/.local/bin:/Users/kamil/.local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/utilities

How to only keep one instance of path and prevent duplication issues in the future?

See Add directory to $PATH if it's not already there and many other similar questions.

Thanks, the post led me to find a more recent answer for zsh: Is there a way to add a directory to my PATH in zsh only if it's not already present?

PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

Or the more zsh-y ways to do it:
path[1,0]=~/.local/bin

path=(~/.local/bin $path)

Does exactly just that: it adds ~/.local/bin to the head of $path (the array tied to colon-separated scalar $PATH variable).
If you run it several times, it prepends it several times.
As having the same directory more than once in $path/$PATH is hardly ever useful, you can just do:
typeset -U path

That sets the unique attribute on the variable:
$ echo ${(t)path}
array-tied-unique-special

$ echo $parameters[path]
array-tied-unique-special

$ typeset -p path
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /home/chazelas/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin )

Which guarantees that all elements of the array are unique.
If an element appears more than once, only the first occurrence is retained.
That means that:
path=( new-element $path )

Will move new-element to the front if it was already there, but path+=( new-element ) won't move it to the back. To move it to the back, that is make sure it's last, you can do:
path=( ${path:#new-element} new-element )

Or remove it first with:
path[(i)new-element]=()

And then add it back at the end with:
path+=(new-element)

The tying of the $path array to the $PATH variable is actually a feature copied from csh/tcsh. In tcsh, arrays can be made unique by assigning them with set -f array=( values... ) or set -l array=( values... ):
tcsh> set -f a= ( a b c b )
tcsh> set -l b= ( a b c b )
tcsh> echo $a, $b
a b c, a c b

With -f, the first of any duplicate is retained, with -l the last.
So appending an element to $path and moving it the back if it was already there can be done with:
set -l path=( $path:q new-element )

And prepending and moving to the front if it was already there with:
set -f path=( new-element $path:q )


Since what I am doing in zsh is a bash thing, should I define paths on the array the way you described it from now on to follow best practices? @chazelas
export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH" to path+=(/usr/local/man/$MANPATH)
export MYVIMRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/.vimrc" to path+=($XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/.vimrc)

@Kamil, not sure what you mean, zsh and bash are two different shells. They have in common that they both took some features from the Bourne, Korn and C-shell, they have borrowed features from each other but are still very different. bash has much fewer features than zsh, in particular it doesn't have the ability of tying arrays to scalar in that csh-style fashion.

What I mean is, defining path on scalar it probably a good practice on bash. But since zsh allows for tying arrays to scalar, which allows for setting unique values, it is more zsh-y to define paths on the array and not scalar directly? Based on the first example you have given, that would be true. I'm just looking to follow best practices here.

When dealing with "colon-separated" lists (PATH is one example) I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935
The addpath function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. delpath -n deletes all non-existent directories from a path. listpath lists a path.
You can get the pathfunc.tgz file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz
These functions should work with zsh, too.
Links checked 2024-06-13 14:34 EDT.

A few common issues in that code like usage of echo, unquoted variables (less of a problem in zsh), confusing line and string. options has let var=$#-$num but in zsh when not in ksh/sh emulation, $#- is the length of the $- parameter (same $#param as in csh). In any case, it's quite overkill and convoluted for zsh where there are builtin array manipulation operators that make this kind of task trivial.
